# .well-known folder persmission denied nginx

Tags: nginx, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to publish PWA to google playstore. I am stuck at a digital asset handshake.

here is my nginx conf for the same-

```
location  /asd/ {
    default_type application/json;
    allow all;
    auth_basic off;
    #alias /app/easygov/user-webapp;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "$http_origin";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    root /app/pwa/user-webapp;
}

location  ^~ /.well-known/ {
default_type application/json;
    allow all;
    auth_basic off;
    #alias /app/pwa/user-webapp;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "$http_origin";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    root /app/pwa/user-webapp;
    log_not_found  off;}
```

For testing, I tried to access the same file from another folder and it worked.
Here is the permission for the well-known folder -

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 centos centos      29 Jan 27 07:01 .well-known
```

For .well-known path, I am getting 404.

Comment: `location  ^~ /.well-known/` - there is a space between `~` and `/`. Can this cause the issue?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch the `^~` is a modifier, and [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) shows it space separated.

Comment: Are there any entries in the error log and access log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while but SELinux was the root cause of the issue.
Giving permission to my .well-known directory solved the issue.

```
sudo chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/.well-known
```